# Написать регулярку для Regex extractor

Tags: json, регулярные-выражения, jmeter

Необходимо записать регулярное выражение, чтобы вытянуть **названия фильмов** с **2000** года. Регулярка нужна для **Regular Expression extractor JMeter**.Я написал что-то подобное (?>"Title":"(.+?)")(.+?), но не понимаю, как пропустить текст между названием и годом и как писать дальше.
Могли ли вы, пожалуйста, объяснить логику написания таких выражений. Я знаю о существовании **json extractor** и то с ним это можно сделать очень легко. Однако в данном мне задании необходимо использовать именно этот инструмент.
Ниже приведен ответ из, которого нужно вытянуть:

```json
{"Data":{"Items":[{"Start":"2018-04-05T05:00:00Z","End":"2018-04-05T05:30:00Z","Title":"Indiana Jones and the Raiders of the Lost Ark","Staff":{"Director":"Steven Spielberg","Starring":"Harrison Ford"},"TimeZone":"UTC","Id":"6ec29f07-c845-4967-9c87-716825265312","Year":1981,"IsNew":false,"ReadOnly":true},{"Start":"2018-06-29T12:00:00Z","End":"2018-06-29T12:30:00Z","Title":"The Lion King","Staff":{"Director":"Roger Allers","Starring":"James Earl Jones"},"TimeZone":"UTC","Id":"9d54f04d-3554-4b61-8077-0cfb79cb86db","Year":1994,"IsNew":false,"ReadOnly":true},{"Start":"2018-06-30T07:30:00Z","End":"2018-06-30T08:00:00Z","Title":"Forrest Gump","Staff":{"Director":"Robert Zemeckis","Starring":"Tom Hanks"},"TimeZone":"UTC","Id":"ed12ee7e-a1ed-4bbf-b7e5-111bf263712c","Year":1994,"IsNew":false,"ReadOnly":true},{"Start":"2018-05-19T04:00:00Z","End":"2018-05-19T04:30:00Z",
{"Start":"2018-04-27T07:00:00Z","End":"2018-04-27T07:30:00Z","Title":"Avengers: Infinity War","Staff":{"Director":"Roger Allers","Starring":"James Earl Jones"},"TimeZone":"UTC","Id":"425b2969-8ec0-4943-93ce-c5a1aec148b0","Year":2018,"IsNew":true,"ReadOnly":true},{"Start":"2018-04-27T07:00:00Z","End":"2018-04-27T07:30:00Z","Title":"Ready Player One","Staff":{"Director":"Steven Spielberg","Starring":"Tye Sheridan"},"TimeZone":"UTC","Id":"425b2969-8ec0-4943-93ce-c5a1aec148b0","Year":2018,"IsNew":true,"ReadOnly":false}],"From":0,"Portion":0,"TotalCount":0},"RedirectViewModel":null,"ExceptionViewModel":null
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что верным ответом на это ваше "задание" будет что-то типа

> JSON не является регулярным языком, поэтому использовать регулярные выражения для работы с ним - не самая лучшая идея

Источник: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/4017

В JMeter имеется [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/), JMESPath имеет [спецификацию](https://jmespath.org/specification.html) и [TCK](https://jmespath.org/compliance.html) так что любое JMESPath выражание будет одинаково работать в любой библиотеке (в отличие от [JSONPath](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath))

В вашем случае JMESPath будет примерно таким:

```
Data.Items[?Year > `2000`].Title
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]